# Ubuntu-VirtualBox-LikeWiseOpen network disaster

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-11.04, likewise-open, dhclient

I've a virtual machine on VirtualBox 4.1.4 with Ubuntu 11.04. It was working perfectly, but after a reboot something really wrong happened: I wasn't able to connect to the internal network (same for NAT).

```
$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet System Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Error creating socket to list interfaces; Permission denied
Can't get list of interfaces.
```

The network interface is PCnet-FAST III.

Additional information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux LinuxFileServer 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
$ sudo ifconfig -a
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:af:f2:c7  
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::a00:27ff:feaf:f2c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:0 (0 B)  Byte TX:3870 (3.8 KB)
          Interrupt:10 

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
          indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
          indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0 
          Byte RX:960 (960.0 B)  Byte TX:960 (960.0 B)
```

Comment: Please show the output of `sudo ifconfig -a` on the guest.

Comment: just edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some tests and I realized that the reason of this mess was that I installed LikeWise-Open from the LikeWise website (I needed the lastest version).

I don't know why, but this happens.

The solution was to change the Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you upgraded your kernel, and some of the VirtualBox kernel modules haven't been rebuilt for the new kernel?  On my host, I have

```
$ lsmod | grep vbox
vboxpci                15608  0
vboxnetadp              5838  0
vboxnetflt             16638  0
vboxdrv              1854398  3 vboxpci,vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
```

Comment: no, I have another Ubuntu 11.04 VM that works perfectly... O.O and I have the same `lsmod | grep vbox` output on the host (Ubuntu 10.10)

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up your `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, then delete it, and reboot.
This should reconfigure your network interfaces.

Comment: it changed the name eth1->eth0. but the problem still there :(